# Cut of first and last char of a string in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list with multiple strings

e.g.:

```
list = ["This", "is", "a", "test"]
```

Now I want to create a function that "cuts out" the first and the last char of each string in the given list.
So for this certain example the output of the function should be:

```
"Tsisaatt"
```

I have already experimented with list[0][1], but this code:

```
newList = []
newList = newList.append(list[0][0])
newList = newList.append(satz[0][1])
newList = newList.append(satz[0][2])
...
...
```

did't do what I want. Did I miss anything or is my idea completely wrong?
Thanks in advance for your feedback!

Comment: Why do you want the `a` to be repeated?

Comment: Your question and expected output don't match! You want to remove first and last character of each string. and may be join it in the end then the output should look like `heis` ? no?

Comment: Repeat any tutorial that includes string indexing.  How do you access the first and last characters of a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**test.py**

```
list = ["This", "is", "a", "test"]
print("".join([l[0] + l[-1] for l in list]))
```

Step 1: Just fetch first item with `l[0]`, plus it with last item with `l[-1]`. It will be `['Ts', 'is', 'aa', 'tt']`.

Step 2: Change the new list to string with `"".join()`.

**Execution result:**

```
$ python test.py
Tsisaatt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acces first element of a string using [0] and last element using [-1]

```
output = ""
for text in text_list:
    if text:
        output += text[0]+text[-1]
print(output)
```

You can use this function

```
def cut_first_and_last(text_list):
    output = ""
    for text in text_list:
        if text:
            output += text[0]+text[-1]
    return output
```

or for one-liner

```
def cut_first_and_last(text_list):
    return "".join([text[0]+text[-1] for text in text_list])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using list comprehension -

```py
output_str = "".join(["".join([x[0], x[-1]]) for x in input_list])
```

the inner `''.join` will join a local list of `x[0]` and `x[-1]` and the outer `''.join` will join all such list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:
newlist.append(mylist[0][0])
newlist.append(mylist[0][-1])

you can write these two lines inside for loop and at last you can join the result

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehensions

```
"".join(i[0]+i[-1] for i in list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't familiar with list comprehension you can use a simple for loop like this:

```
mylist = ["this", "is", "a", "list"]
output_string = ""
for item in word_list:
    output_string.join(item[0], item[1])
print(output_string)
```

If you are familiar with list comprehensions just use this one liner:

```
mylist = ["this", "is", "a", "list"]
print("".join(["".join(item[0],item[1]) for item in mylist])
```